# How I update my Access table through textbox interface and show result into grid view?

Tags: c#

```
String conn="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=E:\\Data.accdb";
string query = "Insert Into Venue values(@venueID,@vanueName)";
OleDbDataAdapter dAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, conn);
OleDbCommandBuilder cBuilder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(dAdapter);
DataTable dTable = new DataTable();
dTable.Rows.Add("@vanueName", textBox1.Text);
dAdapter .Fill (dTable );
dataGridView1 .DataSource =dTable ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not quite sure the Fill method is updating your DB

Comment: so what should i do for this ,

Comment: First make sure you update the DB table by executing the ExecuteNonScalar method.

Comment: no i am still facing a problem kindly can you send me code for this ,or make true to my code

Comment: Please provide appropriate amount of code so that i jus can dumb n compile and fix it. Plus i am struggling to get a SQL here. So just get me the code, ill try ASAP.

Comment: String conn="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=E:\\Data.accdb";
string query = "Insert Into Venue values(@venueID,@vanueName)";
OleDbDataAdapter dAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, conn);
OleDbCommandBuilder cBuilder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(dAdapter);
DataTable dTable = new DataTable();
dTable.Rows.Add("@vanueName", textBox1.Text);
dAdapter .Fill (dTable );
dataGridView1 .DataSource =dTable ;

Comment: Dude use pastebin.com please.

Comment: whats the benefit to use pastebin to me